# How to change color of the selected item from a Xul listbox?

Tags: css, xul

How to change color of the selected item from a Xul listbox?

I've tried something like:

```
listitem:focus {
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}
```

but nothing happens.. and I'm not finding anything in css or xul doc.. (but I'm still looking).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
listitem[selected] { // or listitem[selected=true]
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}
```

`listitem[selected]` applies to all `listitem`s that have an attribute `selected` (or an attribute `selected` that evaluates to true... not quite sure).

Comment: Thanks! Never saw this sintax before.. is it Xul specific? (I'm not a CSS guru either, by the way)

Comment: @Tom Brito: No, it is CSS2.1 attribute selector syntax: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors which got extended in CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors Not sure though if they are all supported in XUL applications..